# Node sass not support in update node version

Tags: node.js, sass, node-sass, node-sass-chokidar

I need help. Previously, I worked on a project where the Node version was 12.22.12, and the Node-sass version was 4. Now, I've updated the React version and Node version. React and React-dom are now running on Node version 16, but Node-sass is not working. How can I resolve this issue and update Node-sass?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aIz6E.png)

Need how to update node-sass in version node 16

Comment: Support, including security support, for Node 16 [ended earlier this year](https://endoflife.date/nodejs). You should upgrade to a supported version of Node.js.

Answer (score 0):

You should read [the manual for node-sass](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass) which says:

> Warning: LibSass and Node Sass are deprecated. While they will continue to receive maintenance releases indefinitely, there are no plans to add additional features or compatibility with any new CSS or Sass features. Projects that still use it should move onto Dart Sass.

So:

```
npm uninstall node-sass
npm install -D sass
```

… and then make any changes needed to your webpack config that might be needed to handle the change.